# not working scrollToPosition recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
    adapter = new AdapterAaaa(aaaaaa.this, model);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(aaaaaa.this);
    rec_aaa.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    rec_aaa.setLayoutManager(manager);
    rec_aaa.setAdapter(adapter);
    rec_aaa.scrollToPosition(4);
```

Why this code doesn't work?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you do see?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you have enough content in your list.
Then try like below.

```
Handler().post {
  rec_aaa.scrollToPosition(4)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably item on position 4 is visible if you want to scroll to top then use this method on layoutmanager, like this

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(aaaaaa.this);
adapter = new AdapterAaaa(aaaaaa.this, model);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = layoutManager;
rec_aaa.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
rec_aaa.setLayoutManager(manager);
rec_aaa.setAdapter(adapter);
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(4, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code block.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            rec_aaa.scrollToPosition(4);
        }
    });
```